# Must all objects have a center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Do all objects have a center of mass.
If yes why? (A mathematical proof is appreciated)
If no, which objects don't

Answer (score 2):

Yes they do. Suppose you have two objects. This is a little like asking if there must be a point halfway between them.

Every object must have a point where it balances.

In one dimension, imagine a ruler. If you pick a point and the ruler falls over to the right, choose a new point a little farther right. It will tilt less strongly. If you go too far, it will tilt to the left. In between there must be a point where it doesn't tilt either way.

You can cut a shape out of cardboard and do the same thing to find a point where it balances. Likewise for a 3 D object.

It is possible the center will not be inside the object. For example, cut a doughnut out of cardboard. The point where it would balance is the center.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, the center of mass is the first moment of the mass distribution. Some mathematical functions lack first moments, so the mathematical answer is no.

The physical answer is yes, since all real things you might call "objects" turn out to have the property we capture with the center of mass concept. If you dispute this, you may prove it wrong by making a physical object that violates this.

Mathematical models of physics exist only in human imagination. You cannot prove *anything* in physics mathematically. Here, there is no rigorous way to say that a particular mathematical object might usefully model a physical object.

Comment: @AXensen Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Yeah you're right. an issue arises if an object has infinite mass... like if the object is "everything in the universe" (assuming an infinite universe). I was thinking there was some issue defining the center of charge when the total charge is zero... but I think I was also just mistaken about that. I deleted my original comment.

Comment: @AXensen It's even trickier than that. The Cauchy distribution has a finite zeroth moment (mass). It does, however, have infinite extent. But lots of mathematical objects used in physics have infinite extent.

Comment: I see that now. I was wrong again! Super interesting distribution. thanks

Comment: If we were to make some assumptions about the real world, like no infinite mass, etc. Could we mathematically show that the integral for centre of mass always converges?

Comment: @ThatApollo777 Yes, you can always choose whatever consistent postulates you wish in mathematics, and use them to prove things about mathematical objects. However, there is no way to prove that every mathematical object one might use to model a physical object conforms to those postulates. We used to think undifferentiable functions were unphysical, but Mandelbrot disabused us of that notion. And I think the Cauchy distribution is a perfectly sensible candidate for a physical mass distribution, but it lacks a first moment.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer to the question may be found in many Classical Mechanics books like [Classical Mechanics by Herbert Goldstein](https://www.amazon.in/Classical-Mechanics-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/8131758915) with many applications, I will restrict the answer to be concise. The answer to the question is "Yes".
I will consider two cases:

1. Discrete case: Consider a body of "n" discrete points moving in space, and let the origin be the point you are at. Let the distance of each point in the body from the origin be $r_1, r_2, r_3, ..., r_n$, and the mass of each point be $m_1, m_2, m_3, ..., m_n$. The position of the center of mass "R" is given by
   $$R = \frac {\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}m_i r_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} m_i}$$

In the above equation, all quantities are Real quantities. This equation only yields an undefined result if the denominator is zero, i.e. total mass of the body is zero.
2. Continous System: Now consider a body composed of a continuous matter. This body can also be considered made up of point particles. The same equation can solve this by changing summations to integrals.
The numerator can be solved by taking a mass element "dm" of the body

```
     `dm = density of body * Area or Volume element of the body`
```

so the center of mass can be given as

$$R = \frac{\int dm*r}{\int dm}$$

The denominator will give the total mass of the body. Putting the equation of the mass element "dm" in the above equation turns the numerator in the integral of "$dr$" or "$d^2 r$" or "$d^3 r$" depending on the dimensions considered.

Unless and until you consider some funky mass value like zero or complex, These equations will always give the position the center of mass "$R$".

Comment: Cauchy distribution is not particularly funky, but has no first moment.

Comment: How would one show that the given integral has a value?